# Connecting external barcode scanner/reader to android device

Tags: android

I need to know how can I connect external barcode reader(this is not know yet which device) to my android device(usb/bluetooth whichever is possible). I am interested to get scanned output of barcode scanner as input in my android device.

Thanks

Comment: you can try usb or bluetooth anything which is connectable :)

Comment: Please visit my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11168282/996493) its same of your requirement

Comment: what pattern of barcode you are going to use ?

Comment: Actually this is unknown right now, is there any api/software available which will be common for all barcode scanner device?(so tat I can use it java(android)).

Comment: yup, the best one is zing library, it is open source and use for all kinds of barcodes :)

Comment: But I dont want scanning in android device instead I will have external barcode reader device using which I can scan barcode and then I can get result of this in my device.